# 403 When trying to access Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, phpmyadmin, centos

When i try to access my Phpmyadmin i get error 403. My username / password is correct. I started receiving this error after updating php to 5.6.

My ssl_error_log (My ip 177)

```
 [Tue Feb 14 12:38:19 2017] [error] [client 177.80.57.117] client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
```

My .htaccess (/usr/share/phpmyadmin)

```
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Logue-se"
 AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/pma_pass
 Require valid-user
```

My phpmyadmin.conf

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   AllowOverride All
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 177.80.57.117
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 177.80.57.117
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 177.80.57.117
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 177.80.57.117
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>
```

Comment: No, my last octet is 117 and my first octet is 177.

Comment: From which PHP version did you upgrade? What happens if you comment out some of the allow/deny rules; can you reduce the problem to a specific set of rules?

Comment: Any rule i set, i get 403, even with default phpmyadmin config. From 5.3.3 to 5.6.30